# How can I get directories of a folder and then its directories' directory and so on...?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, file-handling, directory-structure

**I am coding in C#, if you can't provide the code but you might be able explain how to achieve the result please do answer.**

I want to have the names(path) of all of the folders and files located in a directory and then have their sub directories and files and so on until there are none left.

In simple words I want to map the whole directory.

I want an output similar to the `tree` command in command prompt but only paths:

`├── dirPath (level 0)
│   └── f1 (level 1)
│   │    └──f0 (level 2)
│   │    │   └──file.txt (level 3)
│   │    │   └──f4 (level 3)
│   │    └──f3 (level 2)
│   └── f2 (level 1)`

**Code that I have used but doesn't return what I want:**

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath)) {
      Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

**Output (only returns level 1)**

```
dir/f1
dir/f2
```

**Also tried this code:**

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath)) {
      foreach(string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir)) {
            Console.WriteLine(subdir);
      }
      Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

**Output (returns level 1 and 2)**

```
dir/f1/f0
dir/f1/f3
dir/f1
dir/f2
```

**What I want**

```
dir/f1/f0/file.txt
dir/f1/f0/f4
dir/f1/f3
dir/f1
dir/f2
```

Is there anyway of achieving this? The "getting files" part is not a problem if we can get the directory paths, we can use foreach loop for files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = @"C:\YourPath";
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<string> filesAndFolders = folders.Union(files).ToList();
filesAndFolders.Sort();
```